# Getting a array.map is not a function on a ReactBeautifulDnd dragEnd

Tags: reactjs, use-reducer, react-beautiful-dnd

I am trying to rearrange menu items in categories using react-beautiful-dnd and useReducer.
I get the categories using the `useMenuCategories` hook.
This gets me a list of unusedItems and existing categories in the menu.

Something happens on the reducer after dragEnd and the application breaks. I have also craeted a sandbox for the same.

Please lemme know if you need aditional info.

https://codesandbox.io/embed/epic-mayer-70k98q?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Answer (score 0):

The issue was in the setCategoriesAndUnusedItems action handler in useReducer.
I was incorrectly mapping the state which resulted to a different data structure than expected.